# How do I bind, using a constructor that takes a parameter?

Tags: vb.net, dependency-injection, ninject

Using Ninject, how can I bind using a constructor that accepts a parameter.

I see how I can do this:

```
kernel.Bind(Of IWidget).To(Of Widget)
```

But, what if Widget has a constructor that takes a string? Is there a way to bind this way:

```
kernel.Bind(Of IWidget).To(Of Widget(myParam))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe `.WithConstructorArgument` will suffice for your need:

```
Bind(Of IWidget).To(Of Widget)
                .WithConstructorArgument("constructorArgumentOne", ...)
```

Comment: Yup. Needless to say, after looking forever, 2 minutes after I posted this question I found the answer. Thanks.